# How can I set context to be default in kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

When I do `kubectl config get-contexts`:

```
CURRENT   NAME                          CLUSTER                                                            AUTHINFO                                                           NAMESPACE
          kubernetes-admin@kubernetes   kubernetes                                                         kubernetes-admin
*         qa-1                        arn:aws:eks:xxxxxx150:cluster/ocean-qa   xxx:xxx:cluster/xxxx-RH36mmA4   xx-xx-tulw
```

I have multiple contexts defined in the configuration file. I would like to set 'kubernetes-admin@kubernetes' cluster as the default each time I use kubectl. What command do I need for this?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I toggle between kubernetes context of various deployed apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169427/how-can-i-toggle-between-kubernetes-context-of-various-deployed-apps)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the use-context command to set the current context. Then kubectl will always use this context till you change it again. So also after a restart.

`kubectl config use-context kubernetes-admin@kubernetes`